# How to diagnose: Ubuntu 16.04 error 403 forbidden in response to GET from updates.drupal.org

Tags: ubuntu, drupal

None of the 3 Drupal websites on this server are able to show available updates. Error message is:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: GET
>   http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/addtoany/8.x?site_key=_8FTNSp2dxJwAhgk4-OUW6oti3JrF61GE2q_yozrhak&version=8.x-1.10&list=addtoany
>   resulted in a 403 Forbidden response:

Cannot determine how to diagnose this.

Comment: Works for me. Did you configure a proxy server or something?

Comment: The app was rebuilt and then the problem started. Running Ubuntu on AWS server is main app. DB is mysql on RDS. Public storage on S3. SOLR runs on another Ubuntu instance. Running memcache, too.   --- What would this error indicate?  How can I diagnose a solution?